# Flutter size of the container

Tags: flutter, containers, mpmediaquery

I have problem with the container. A have an app with the AppBar and the column below. Below AppBar I added a container with the height of 300 an then sizedBox with height of 16. Then I wanted to add last container which should fill rest of the screen, i am getting the errors all the time and i can not calculate proper size of this container.

Code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class TimerPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TimerPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var height = size.height;

    Provider provider = Provider.of<DrillProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'AIM TIMER',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            'ABC: ABC',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff5F5F5F)),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'ABC: ABC',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff5F5F5F)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          ParameterDisplay(
                              text: 'ABC',
                              result: 'ABC',
                          Column(
                            children: const [
                              ParameterDisplay(text: 'ABC', result: 'ABC'),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 16,
                              ),
                              ParameterDisplay(text: 'ABC', result: 'ABC'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const ParameterDisplay(
                              text: 'ABC', result: 'ABC'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 16,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          CustomButton(
                            text: 'ABC',
                            onPressed: () {},
                            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                            gradient: const LinearGradient(
                              colors: [Color(0xffF17E0F), Color(0xffEF9034)],
                            ),
                          ),
                          CustomButton(
                            text: 'ABC',
                            onPressed: () {},
                            backgroundColor: const Color(0xff262525),
                            textColor: const Color(0xff5F5F5F),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: (height -
                    360 -
                    kToolbarHeight -
                    kBottomNavigationBarHeight),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: const Color(0xff2E2E2E),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            'REVIEW',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xff707070), fontSize: 20),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      const Divider(
                        color: Color(0xff2E2E2E),
                        thickness: 2,
                      ),
                      const Text('okqweqweqweqweqwe'),
                      const Text('okqwewqeqw'),
                      const Text('okqweqweqw'),
                      const Text('okqweqweqwe'),
                      const Text('okwqeqweqwe'),
                      const Text('okweqeweqweqw'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use Expanded, I tried to calculate it whit MediaQuery. Nothing is working for me. When i put Container as a parent of all widget it is taking whole space. Any idea?

Comment: Expanded is supposed to work here. What happened when you use Expanded here? Can you share your result?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your container with Expanded widget to get available space.

```dart
 Expanded(
   child: Container(
```

If you need to get size , you can use LayoutBuilder widget like

```
body: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (p0, constraints) {
    final width  = constraints.maxWidth;
    final height = constraints.maxHeight;
  return  Padding(
```

More about [flutter-adaptive-responsive design](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive).